# Fit a text optimally in two textviews

Tags: android, textview, android-appwidget

I have a long test to be displayed within a TextView an android appwidget. That text can come entirely within two TextViews but not in a single TextView.

So what I was doing is using a ViewFlipper with two TextViews and displaying the entire text.

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateFirstView="true"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="6000"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_text1_gingerbread"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_text2_gingerbread"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

The problem is splitting the original text into two parts. The text is fetched from the network. I need to calculate the substring of the text to be displayed in each of the two TextViews. Any ideas how to proceed with this?

**Additional Bonus**: Currently this appwidget runs only on Android api level <11 (below android 3.0). On above api levels I have StackWidget to handle this and this appwidget is disabled. Can this be handled in android 4.0 and above where the appwidgets can be resized and thus the TextView sizes are variable?